# Can I associate an automated test case to a Testcase workitem from a different Collection in Azure DevOps?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, test-explorer

I have two collections in my Azure DevOps server.
CollectionA contains a repository with automated test cases, CollectionB is where my test case work items are.
My goal is to associate automated testcases from CollectionA to test cases from Collection B.

I have searched [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/associate-automated-test-with-test-case?view=azure-devops-2019) so I am aware of how it works in general. Is there a way to achieve this type of association?

Comment: You could check your test project into the same team project in Collection B.

Answer (score 1):

No. Collections are intended to be completely isolated instances that share nothing. From a technical perspective, in on-prem TFS/Azure DevOps Server, collections exist in **completely separate databases**.

You should not be using multiple collections unless you need that level of isolation. It sounds like you should be using two separate team projects within the same collection. Although I strongly recommend that test code should be kept right alongside the code that is being tested, in the same repository.

Comment: Thanks, I heard that since Azure DevOps 2019 there is a possibility to link work items from different collections so I thought maybe there have been changes.

Answer (score 0):

You could check your test project into the same team project in Collection B, or migrate the work items from Collection B to the same team project in Collection A, by exporting them to excel and then remap to the new collection and publish them.